# facebook login not working php sdk 3.0 oauth2.0

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

I am using facebook api 3.00 (the one from github). When I click on the login link I am redirected to the authentication page of facebook.

When it comes back it's showing the `$user` as null, but this is working properly:

```
print $facebook->getAccessToken()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it. If the $user is null then try accessing facebook with out login. Probably that will not work (Atleast in case this was the problem). **Only now it will show** that there is some problem with the certificate. 
`Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;`

And the certificate issue was resolved. After which the user authentication also worked.